# hooking up 2 additional monitor to my Dell inspiron 1525

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell inspiron 1525 running windows 7 that has a VGA plug and A HDMI plug and would like to hook up two monitors plus the laptop monitor for the total of 3 extended displays. Can it be done and how?

Comment: Are you looking for different content on each monitor?  Typically, the external connectors are alternate connections to the same output.

Answer (score 0):

A Dell inspiron 1525 does not support more than two monitors at once.

> Only two displays can run simultaneously

[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19374038)

Comment: That's what I suspecting. Thank you for your time.